# Wordpress, page 2 shows the same posts as page 1

Tags: pages

I am working on a premium that got it's frontpage as a 'grid' here's what it looked like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y392U.png

Then i installed a plugin named: Blog Layout by WebLumia Infomatics to make my frontpage show up as a 'normal blog' and it now looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYBzG.png which is perfect.

But when i click to page 2 to see more posts, it just shows the the same as on page 1

I am not really sure what to change in the plugin code but im hoping some guys here could help me. I already have an idéa where the change has to be made but im not sure at all.

Here's what some of the code look like

```
switch( $this->type ) {
case 'multipart':
    // Multipart page
    $posts_per_page = 1;
    $paged = max( 1, absint( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) );
    $total_pages = max( 1, $numpages );
    break;
case 'users':
    // WP_User_Query
    $posts_per_page = $query->query_vars['number'];
    $paged = max( 1, floor( $query->query_vars['offset'] / $posts_per_page ) + 1 );
    $total_pages = max( 1, ceil( $query->total_users / $posts_per_page ) );
    break;
default:
    // WP_Query
    $posts_per_page = intval( $query->get( 'posts_per_page' ) );
    $paged = max( 1, absint( $query->get( 'paged' ) ) );
    $total_pages = max( 1, absint( $query->max_num_pages ) );
    break;
}
```

Comment: There should be code after that switch that actually does the pagination-- perhaps `paginate_links`? Post that code please, and also the code that produces the `$query` object-- `$query = new WP_Query($args);`, something like that.

Comment: Not named paginate_links in my whole code :-(

The only i got was WP_Query from this

<?php }
function lumia_pagination( $args = array() ) {
 
 if ( !is_array( $args ) ) {
  $argv = func_get_args();
  $args = array();
  foreach ( array( 'before', 'after', 'options' ) as $i => $key )
   $args[ $key ] = $argv[ $i ];
 }
 $args = wp_parse_args( $args, array(
  'before' => '',
  'after' => '',
  'options' => array(),
  'query' => $GLOBALS['wp_query'],
  'type' => 'posts',
  'echo' => true

Comment: Nonetheless, edit what additional code you found into the question.

Comment: The continue:
 ) );

 extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP );
 $instance = new LBNavi_Call( $args ); 

 list( $posts_per_page, $paged, $total_pages ) = $instance->get_pagination_args();

 if ( 1 == $total_pages && !$options['always_show'] )
  return;

 $pages_to_show = 100;
 $larger_page_to_show = 3;
 $larger_page_multiple = 10;
 $pages_to_show_minus_1 = $pages_to_show - 1;
 $half_page_start = floor( $pages_to_show_minus_1/2 );
 $half_page_end = ceil( $pages_to_show_minus_1/2 );
 $start_page = $paged - $half_page_start;

Comment: __[Edit] the code into the question!__ Code is nearly unreadable in the comments.

Comment: try to add <?php  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  ?> and append $paged to WP_Query('your_query&paged='.$paged)

Comment: I'm can't since i dont got enough points/badges im afraid.

I tried, didn't work :-(

Comment: This question looks very similar to [your last question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/116397/32110).  Have you tried what we recommended there yet, namely, temporarily switch themes to Twenty Twelve or Twenty Thirteen and see if the problem persists?